# What is the time complexity of iterating through a nested file directory?

Tags: time-complexity

If I have directory with subdirectories or files, and the subdirectories can be nested at an unknown number of levels, what is the time complexity of traversing through the entire directory?

My thought was O(number of files) because it's only at the leaf nodes that you would call a function to say, append file contents to a larger file. But I'm not entirely sure. Can someone walk me through how to determine this?

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity grows linearly when you add a file. So it can only be O(n) where n is the amount of files. Traversals are always O(n).